# Map External JSON file to specified Format in Springboot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I have an external JSON file that I want to map into a specified format like this which I have converted from CSV (with comma delimited) format to JSON format.

First I have to read the converted JSON file which  is not straightforward and then convert it to a specified format like this

```
{
    [
        {
        Test_Scenario = GreenMile,
        Test_Case = GM_Login,
        Step_No = "",
        Status = Pass,
        Description = "",
        Detailed Description = "",
        Expected_Data = "",
        Actual_Data = "",
        Execution_Date = 08_24_2022,
        Execution_Time = 0:0:10,
        Error_Screenshot = "",
        LastWebPage = ""
        },
        {
        Test_Scenario = Aries,
        Test_Case = AriesCreateUser,
        Step_No = "",
        Status = Pass,
        Description = "",
        Detailed Description = "",
        Expected_Data = "",
        Actual_Data = "",
        Execution_Date = 08_24_2022,
        Execution_Time = 0:0:10,
        Error_Screenshot = "",
        LastWebPage = ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Current JSON data from which we have to convert into the above-mentioned format:

```
[ {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "GreenMile~GM_Login~~Pass~~~~~08_24_2022~0:0:6~~",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "~TC01~1~Pass~LAUNCH url=>https://glccd-test.greenmile.com/#/login~LAUNCH url=>https://glccd-test.greenmile.com/#/login~~~08_24_2022~~~null",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "~TC01~2~Pass~SET uname=>psingh~SET uname=>psingh~~~08_24_2022~~~null",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "~TC01~3~Pass~SET pass=>coke123~SET pass=>coke123~~~08_24_2022~~~null",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "~TC01~4~Pass~CLICK //*[@id=\"LoginBox\"]/div[1]/button~CLICK //*[@id=\"LoginBox\"]/div[1]/button~~~08_24_2022~~~null",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "GreenMile~GM_CreateUser~~Fail~~~~~08_24_2022~0:1:4~~",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "~TC01~1~Fail~Object Not found: Identifier=XPATH Identifier Value=//*[contains(text()",
  "" : "Administration)] Test Data=~Object Not found: Identifier=XPATH Identifier Value=//*[contains(text()"
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "GreenMile~GM_Logout~~Skipped~\"Skipped due to failure in previous case\"~~~~08_24_2022",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "GreenMile~GM_Login~~Skipped~\"Skipped due to failure in previous case\"~~~~08_24_2022",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "GreenMile~GM_ResetPassword~~Skipped~\"Skipped due to failure in previous case\"~~~~08_24_2022",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "",
  "" : ""
}, {
  "Test_Scenario~Test_Case~Step_No~Status~Description~Detailed Description~Expected_Data~Actual_Data~Execution_Date~Execution_Time~Error_Screenshot~LastWebPage" : "GreenMile~GM_Logout~~Skipped~\"Skipped due to failure in previous case\"~~~~08_24_2022",
  "" : ""
} ]
```

Comment: Ok, what is your question?

Comment: The first example you show is not valid JSON. But if it was, you'd have to loop through all the keys of the second JSON and split them by tilde in order to restructure them. Either way, its all about writing the mapping code from JSON 2 to JSON 1, no magic can occur here as the data are completely unstructured